# Как посмотреть тип переменной java?

Tags: java

Я понимаю что в java "строгая типизация". Однако, если например я сделал множество приведений в коде и хочу вывести тип переменной в конце, как мне это сделать?

Вот пример в JavaScript и python

```
var a = 5;
typeof(a);
// если вывести последнюю сроку, то ответ будет - Integer
```

```
print(type(object))
```

Comment: Добавьте пример

Comment: Это относится не к строгости, а к статичности. Теоретически можно через рефлексию, но она медленная и её использование лишает вас всех преимуществ статической типизации. Её применения стоит избегать, если вы не занимаетесь разработкой фреймворка или инструментальных средств.

Comment: Да и приведения в java-коде - это маркер архитектурных проблем, их использование тоже стоит сводить к минимуму.

Comment: если вы привели экземпляр класса к суперклассу, то это возможно всегда и никаких проверок не требуется. мало того, на этом стоит все ооп. если же вы пытаетесь узнать, какой именно экземпляр класса лежит в конкретной переменной,то у вас с вероятностью 99 процентов проблемы с архитектурой, потому как для того объект и приводится к родителю, чтобы потом использовать множество различных объектов одинаковым способом - вызывая методы у переменной типа родителя. разумеется,есть метод getClass(),который получает реальный класс объекта в переменной, после чего можно узнать имя-getName()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно вывести тип примитивной переменной (int, double, long ...), то это вроде как в джаве не возможно. Но можно с легкостью узнать что за класс ты используешь.

```
    yourClass.getClass().getName();
```

это тебе покажет имя класа в виде (com.company.example.yourClassName), или можешь использовать :

```
    yourClass.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

это возвращает исключительно имя класа. А если тебе нужно в условии проверить допустим является ли переменная строкой то пригодится следущее:

```
    if(s instanceof String)
```

вместо String, можешь поставить любой класс, который тебе нужен.

Comment: Как на счет  String typeOf(int a){return "int";} и так для каждого примитивного типа? :D